# Make javascript that redirects after opening a popup

Tags: javascript

I have the following constantcontact form they provided, After they click on submit, it opens a constant contact page. However I would like that it redirect also to a page after they click on submit

```
<form name="ccoptin" action="http://visitor.r20.constantcontact.com/d.jsp" target="_blank" method="post" style="margin-bottom:2;">
<input type="hidden" name="llr" value="cjdttecab">
<input type="hidden" name="m" value="1101813878050">
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="oi">
<font style="font-weight: normal; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#000000;">Email:</font> <input type="text" name="ea" size="20" value="" style="font-size:10pt; border:1px solid #999999;">
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit" class="submit" style="font-family:Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:10pt;">
</form>
```

Comment: Can someone pls help me, I pasted some html code in the question with the <pre> tag, and its not showing correctly the question??

Comment: highlight the code thats not showing and press control+k on your keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated to 2023 code

The form generator for constantcontact is deprecated so I removed it

Give the form an ID and use setTimeout to defer the thank you to after the submit

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // when page has loaded
  document.getElementById('ccoptin').addEventListener('submit',() => setTimeout(() => {
      location.replace('thanks.html')
    }, 100)
  );
});
```

```html
<form id="ccoptin" action="pageyouwantoload.php" target="_blank" method="post">
```

Comment: Strange. Chrome 14 and 15 on Win7 does not.

Comment: Hopefully the end user doesnt have a slow internet connection or and old pc... i hardly thing 100ms is going to be enough time in every case of the world....

Comment: the 100ms are for chrome to get over the seemingly shocking event of the form submission. Not the time it takes to return from the submission.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using JSP to parse the response, couldnt you just, at the end of your code that handles the form insert this:

```
response.sendRedirect("your/URL/here");
```

and just do this the normal way? or is there a reason you need to do this with javascript?

ahhhh n/m I just realized that you do not have control of the receiving script at constant contact - Don't they have a setting you can send to have the browser redirected back to a page of your choosing? I would look into that.

EDIT:

The timeout function below will work but it assumes the end user has javascript enabled. Furthermore, 100ms is not a lot of time to wait - if the network lags for any reason the post will not be sent so it will not work 100% of the time and thats a promise.

The proper way to do this, would be to use this:
http://community.constantcontact.com/t5/Documentation/Constant-Contact-Signup-Form-Generator-CCSFG/ba-p/25033

To set up a privately hosted solution that uses the api. This requires pretty little programming knowledge at all and you'd still be able to skin the form you generate to match your site. It does run in PHP so your server would have to support that, but most do these days.

Comment: Already posted that link. However the 100 ms is not the time to send the form, it is the time Chrome needed to get over the shock of sending a form. With a tiny delay in the replace, the form works fine